# RestKit pathPattern using ravenDb id

Tags: routes, restkit

I'm using RavenDB for my persistence which is giving my objects identifiers like this:

networks/33
users/322

etc where the route to load my network restfully is mydomain.com/networks/33

So I'm wondering if I will have any issues mapping my responseDescriptors in one spot on app initialisation.

Let's say I have this for my Network response descriptor:

```
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor
responseDescriptorWithMapping:networkMapping
pathPattern:@":\\identifier"
keyPath:@"Network"
```

and this for my User response descriptor:

```
[manager addResponseDescriptor:[RKResponseDescriptor
responseDescriptorWithMapping:networkMapping
pathPattern:@":\\identifier"
keyPath:@"User"
```

When I request an object at mydomain.com/networks/33 or mydomain.com/users/323 how does the router know which response descriptor to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your base URL is set to `mydomain.com`.

Your path patterns are wrong, they should be set to:

```
@"networks/:identifier"
@"users/:identifier"
```

Now the response descriptors can be distinguished based on the path.

Comment: That means the url would resolve to networks/networks/33 instead of networks/33. The ravenDb id generator gives me an id of networks/33 not 33

Comment: The response descriptor path is used to understand the result of the URL, not to create the URL. The identifier in the path pattern is a description of the URL, not an identifier in your code. If you're using routing then the path patterns would need to be different for that as they use the object identity to generate the URLs.